# Drawbacks of using boost::shared_ptr instead of boost::optional

Tags: c++, boost

Can someone explain if there is a drawback of using `boost::shared_ptr` to represent a value which could be `null` or undefined rather than using `boost::optional`, in terms of memory and performance ?

I have seen, where I work, many people using `boost::shared_ptr` to represent a value which can be `null`. Is there an overhead in terms of performance or memory usage ?

Comment: use `std::unique_ptr` to avoid most of the overhead

Comment: @BryanChen `unique_ptr` will still require you to perform dynamic allocation unless you get very creative with the deleter and type semantics.

Comment: There may be an impact on the performance and memory usage of someone reading the code. Why force `shared_ptr` to do something `optional` was designed for?

Answer (score 5):

Besides the obvious fact that a `shared_ptr` has to also manage a thread-safe reference count, there is also allocation. `optional` is stack-based, which means that it will not perform any dynamic allocation. A `shared_ptr` will have to perform at least one (often two: object and control block) dynamic allocations.

`optional` does none of the above.

Answer (score 3):

`shared_ptr` has many additional responsibilities - like reference counting - so yes there's an overhead in memory and synchronisation.  It would be silly to use `shared_ptr` for this reason alone.

Answer (score 2):

`optional<T>` is either an instance of `T` or not.  `shared_ptr` is either an owning smart pointer to `T` or not.

Anything that is correct and efficient to pass by-value will be correct and efficient to pass by-optional compared to a shared pointer.

Allocations are reasonably expensive operations, and by-value is sometimes what you mean.  In addition, `optional` clearly says what you mean, while a `shared_ptr` has many meanings.